# Determine AM/PM from string as "05:00:00"

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a string that looks like "05:00:00". I'm using the following to convert it to a datetime in C#.

`var time = DateTime.ParseExact(row.l_file_time, "HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US" ));
var x = time.ToString("tt");`

c# thinks 05:00 is on the morning and it should be PM. Is there a way to conversion take account the times are based in the work hours?

Comment: No, what defines "work hours" for a specific culture? You will need to include that kind of logic yourself. Note that DateTime uses 24-hour time, so 5:00 will always be 5 AM.

Comment: If you ask me to determine AM/PM from "05:00:00", I would say AM. Why should it be PM? Work hours is a largely loose definition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, DateTime uses 24-hour time, so parsing "5:00" will always return the equivalent of 5 AM.

"Work hours" are not constant, even within a culture (maybe I work at night!) so any kind of logic like this needs to be written by you, and is not provided in the framework.

This logic could easily look like:

```
if (time.Hour < 9) // less than 9AM, it must be PM!
  time.AddHours(12);
```